# jQuery prevUntil() include start selector and end selector

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, traversal

I would like to select the start and end selector for the prevUntil() or nextUntil() jQuery selector methods. If I implement these methods now, it grabs everything between the two selectors given.

i.e. `$('p').prevUntil('h1')` will not include the p and h1 element, only those between them. How could I also select the p and h1 elements as well as though between?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take a look at the [.addBack method](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) to add the results of the previous selector to the current matches.  Combining that with the [.prev method](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) seems to do the trick:

```
$('p').prevUntil('h1').addBack().prev('h1').addBack();
```

Comment: @Mark, @DavidFullerton :- +1 for both of you. It took almost 1 hour to find me this exact solution. +1  for `andSelf()`

Comment: Just FYI, [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) is deprecated and you should use [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) instead