# Jquery nextUntil and prevUntil including issue

Tags: jquery, html, nextuntil

I am trying to include first and last selectors along with nextUntil and prevUntil

**JQUERY**

```
$('.selectedDay').parent().prevUntil('li.weeks').css('background', '#F00');

$('.selectedDay').parent().nextUntil('li.weeksClose').css('background', '#F00');
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tx0f27fj/1/)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery prevUntil() include start selector and end selecter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770588/jquery-prevuntil-include-start-selector-and-end-selecter)

Comment: andSelf() is deprecated in new version.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Those functions are selecting only between elements but It should include given class elements also

Comment: Include '.weeks' and '.weeksClose' elements also. Could you see Fiddle

Comment: Well you could simply determine the previous/next element of .weeks/.weeksClose beforehand, and then use _those_ as arguments for prev-/nextUntil ... (of course in that case you need to take the edge cases into account somehow.)

Comment: Could you please provide the source code or may edit fiddle please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.selectedDay').parent().prevAll('.weeks').first().css('background', '#F00');

$('.selectedDay').parent().nextAll('li.weeksClose').first().css('background', '#F00');
```

Comment: Then It's selecting all classes which has weeks and weeksClose

Comment: Then It's selecting classes which has weeks and weeksClose not between elements

Answer (score 1):

## Solution using *jquery* (javascript library)

Since

- `li.weeks` is preceded by `li.weeksClose`; and
- `li.weeksClose` is followed by `li.weeks`

why not simply use:

```
$('.selectedDay').parent().prevUntil('li.weeksClose').css('background', '#F00');
$('.selectedDay').parent().nextUntil('li.weeks').css('background', '#F00');
```

---

## Solution using *axe* (CSS Library)

Alternatively, instead of using a javascript library like **jQuery**, you can use a CSS Library like **axe**.

You will need to use the following two axe selectors:

- `<` selects **immediate parent** (it's the opposite of `>` in standard CSS)
- `!` selects **any previous sibling** (it's the opposite of `~` in standard CSS)

Then you can write the following style rules:

```
.selectedDay < li ! li,
.selectedDay < li ~ li {
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.selectedDay < li ! li.weeks ! li,
.selectedDay < li ~ li.weeksClose ~ li {
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.selectedDay < li ! li,
.selectedDay < li ~ li {
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.selectedDay < li ! li.weeks ! li,
.selectedDay < li ~ li.weeksClose ~ li {
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<ul class="x-axis">
  <li class="td-front weeks"><span>30<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-front"><span>31<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day firstFortNight1"><span>01<br> W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>02<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span >03<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>04<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day weeksClose"><span>05<br>W</span>
    <p>Week Avg : 9.15</p>
  </li>
  <li class="td-day weeks"><span>06<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>07<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>08<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span class="selectedDay">09<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>10<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>11<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day weeksClose"><span>12<br>W</span>
    <p>Week Avg : 9.15</p>
  </li>
  <li class="td-day weeks"><span>13<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>14<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day firstFortNight15"><span>15<br> W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day secondFortNight16"><span>16<br> W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>17<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>18<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day weeksClose"><span>19<br>W</span>
    <p>Week Avg : 9.15</p>
  </li>
  <li class="td-day weeks"><span>20<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>21</span><br>W</li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>22<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>23<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>24<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>25<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day weeksClose"><span>26<br>W</span>
    <p>Week Avg : 9.15</p>
  </li>
  <li class="td-day weeks"><span>27<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>28<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>29<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day"><span>30<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-day secondFortNight30"><span>31<br> W</span></li>
  <li class="td-back"><span>01<br>W</span></li>
  <li class="td-back weeksClose"><span>02<br>W</span>
    <p>Week Avg : 9.15</p>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://rouninmedia.github.io/axe/axe.js"></script>
```

Comment: how to get individual values. $('.selectedDay').parent().prevUntil('li.weeksClose').text() is giving complete string.

Comment: This is a different question from your original question. Please ask a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Done.

```
$('.selectedDay').parent().prevAll('.weeks').first().css('background', '#F00');
    $('.selectedDay').parent().prevUntil('.weeks').css('background', '#F00');

    $('.selectedDay').parent().nextAll('li.weeksClose').first().css('background', '#F00');

    $('.selectedDay').parent().nextUntil('li.weeksClose').css('background', '#F00');
```